# mysql dump export a table excluding more specific row

Tags: mysql, cmd

What I'm trying to do is find the command to export a table excluding specific entries. Here are the various options I tried but without achieving the desired result.

The approach works only for export of a table but excluding one record:

```
mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME usertable --where username!='root'
```

If I try to use other operator for exclude more data, as below, the export failed:

```
mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME usertable --where username!='root' and username!='root2'

mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME usertable --where "username not in('root','root2')"
```

What is a functional approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax for the where is wrong as mysql needs a string for that

```
mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME usertable --where="username!='root' and username!='root2'"

mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME usertable --where="username not in('root','root2')"
```

please read more in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where)